# Submitting a JSONP to a PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

As part of my application, I want to submit a JSON object to a PHP script which returns a JSON response. The domain is not following the same-origin policy, i.e., the JSON is submitted from a different domain, so after doing some research, I understand that I need to use JSONP. After spending more than 10 hours now, I can't think of any other solution. Can anyone help me to understand where my problem is?

Javascript snippet:

```js
var jsondata = {
        "variablA": "valueA",
        "variables": {
            "variableB": "valueB",
            "variableC": "valueC"
        };

        var encodedjson = JSON.stringify(jsondata);



        $.ajax({
            url: 'update.php',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                "data": encodedjson
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                //On error do this
                $.mobile.loading('hide')
                if (xhr.status == 200) {

                    alert(ajaxOptions);
                } else {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            }
        });
```

PHP:

```html
$array = json_decode($_REQUEST['data'], true);

$valueA = $array['variableA'];
$valueB = $array['variables']['variableB'];
$valueC = $array['variables']['variableC'];


$values = array('variableB' => $valueB, 'variableC' => $valueC);

$respencode = array('variableA' => $valueA, 'variables' => $values);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($respencode);
```

Comment: What have you read about JSON-P? You can't turn a standard JSON response into JSON-P just by changing the `dataType` in your jQuery `$.ajax()`. The server-side code needs to wrap the JSON in a function call, i.e., instead of responding with `{"key":"val"}` it should return `callback({"key":"val"});`

Comment: POST and JSONP do not mix. And your PHP code is not returning JSONP

Answer (score 0):

For Ajax to know that it is dealing with a jsonP request, You need to rewrite the url with a callback query string like So :

url: 'update.php?callback=?'

Comment: jQuery takes care of that for you because of the `dataType: "jsonp"` parameter, but the server-side code still has to return a response in the right format.